# The value of a European call option, Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Problem:

In the Black & Scholes model, the price $S_t$ of a risky asset at time $t$ is given by the formula

$$S_t = \text{exp}\{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma B_t \}$$

The value of a European call option, with maturity $T$ and strike price $K$, is $(S_T − K)^+$ at time $T$. If $T > t$, compute explicitly

$$E[(S_T − K)^+|\mathcal{F}_t
].$$

In the given solution, it reads:

Note: \begin{equation}
\begin{split}E[(S_T − K)^+|\mathcal{F}_t] &= E[(S_0\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T +σB_T\} - K)^+ |\mathcal{F}_t] \\ 
&= E[(S_0\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t+t) +σ(B_T-B_t+B_t)\} - K)^+ |\mathcal{F}_t] \\
& = E[(S_t\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t) +σ(B_T-B_t)\} - K)^+ |\mathcal{F}_t]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I fail to see why

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S_T &= \text{exp}\{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma B_t \} \\
 &= (S_0\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T +σB_T\} - K) \\
& = (S_0\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t+t) +σ(B_T-B_t+B_t)\} \\
&= S_t\text{exp}\{(r−\frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T-t) +σ(B_T-B_t)\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

holds. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the price process in the risk neutral framework is $S_t=S_0e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t}$ for $S_0>0$ where $W_t$ is the driving Brownian motion. So if $T>t$ we have ($S_t$ is always strictly positive)
$$S_T=S_t\frac{S_T}{S_t}=S_t\frac{S_0e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)T+\sigma W_T}}{S_0e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t}}=S_te^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)}$$
The solution you are provided with says, equivalently:
$$\begin{aligned}S_T&=S_0e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t+t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t+W_t)}=\\
&=S_0e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)}\underbrace{e^{(r-\sigma^2/2)t+\sigma W_t}}_{=S_t/S_0}=\\
&=S_te^{(r-\sigma^2/2)(T-t)+\sigma (W_T-W_t)}\end{aligned}$$